# Dropbox missing icon.. Sometimes

Tags: debian, dropbox, icons

I'm stuck with a problem about Dropbox icon.

I'm using `Debian 7 Wheezy`. I've installed Dropbox.

When I run manually:

```
dropbox start -i
```

-> Everything is fine and I've an icon on the top-right corner of my screen.

When I run a script with this command from a crontask (from the same user on both), everything is fine but there's not any icon on the top-right corner.

I've check and compare processes from the 2 different starts. Nothing is different except pids numbers.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this mystery?

Is there any difference between starting a script from `cron` and starting it manually ? (I say it again, each time it's the same use who starts manual command or crontask).

Here is my script:

```
# my_script.sh
dropbox start | grep jour
if [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
  echo 'dropbox is already running'
else
  echo "Dropbox isn't started"
  dropbox start -i
fi
```

**Edit:**
`libappindicator1` is installed

Comment: How did you install dropbox?

Comment: From .deb file. https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx

Comment: May be this thread have a look at this [Icon Missing](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201545695-After-upgrade-to-3-x-the-dropbox-tray-icon-is-missing-XFCE-Xubuntu-14-04-1-x64-)

Comment: I think I've already tried everything on this post. I've exactly the same behavior by using `dropbox.py` file by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem on `Debian` but not on `Ubuntu`.

Here is my crontask:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0; send-notify "`/home/username/Documents/myscript.sh`"
```

Export DISPLAY variable with your specific value is required when you start it from crontask.